# Load asp:charts one at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a aspx page with 4 `asp:charts`, each one with its type, data and so on.

The problem is that one of them is taking longer than the others, and I was wondering if there is any possibility to display the charts as soon they are loaded, instead waiting that all the 4 charts are loaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just went with:

```
Parallel.Invoke(() => graph1(), () => graph2(), () => graph3(), () => graph4());
```